# Scrolling to specific position with Javascript failed

Tags: javascript, html, window

I'm new to HTML and Javascript and want to create a link that, when clicked on, scrolls to a specific position in the page. I made some research online and came up with the following solution:

My HTML file:

```
...
<a href="#" onclick="scroll()">My link</a>
...
```

My Javascript (which I include in the `<head>` tag):

```
function scroll() {
    window.scrollTo({ top: 300, left: 0, behavior: "smooth" });
}
```

However this does not work well, because every time I click the link, the page just scrolls to the very top of the page, regardless to what position I set in `window.scrollTo`. Can somebody point out where my mistake is and how to do it right?

Thanks!

Comment: why use JS in the first place and not a technique called `anchor`? You use as hyper reference: `#id` which will then scroll automatically to the element with that id.

Comment: I use Javascript because the anchor method adds that specific ID to the navigation bar in the browser and I want to avoid that. Plus, I don't want to scroll to the exact position of one given element, but to a certain numbers of pixels above it (This is to prevent my navbar from overlapping with headings).

Answer (score 0):

I do not know your html structure completely
Maybe this method will help you :

```js
function goToTarget(){
  var element = document.getElementById("target");

  element.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth", block: "end", inline: "nearest"});
}
```

```css
#target{
  margin-top:100pc;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="goToTarget()"> click me </button>

<div id="target"> i am target </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I honestly din't know what I am doing wrong, but this doesn't work for me. I created a button, included the script, entered the specific target ID and checked every thing for typos. Still, it doesn't scroll anywhere when the button is clicked. I am using semantic HTML, could that be the reason? Or perhaps because I declared scroll-behaviour: smooth in my CSS?

Answer (score 0):

Going on the assumption that you want a *smooth* scroll to a specific position on the *same* page, you could setup your HTML as tacoshy recommended, using an anchor for the place you’ll click and a reference `#id` for your destination:

```
<a href="#my-link" class="same-page-link">My link</a>

<h2 id="my-link">My Link Section</h2>
```

Then, if you’re using jQuery on your page, you can add a listener to the anchor tag:

```
$(".same-page-link").on("click", function(event) {
  var $target;

  event.preventDefault();

  $target = $($(this).attr("href"));

  $("html, body").animate({
    scrollTop: $target.offset().top - 50
  }, 1000, "swing").promise().done(function() {
    $target.attr('tabindex', '0'); //Adding tabindex for elements not focusable
    $target.focus(); //Setting focus
  });

  return false;
});
```

the `- 50` is to offset the top of the scroll position from a fixed header, if you have one.

If you’re not using jQuery, there is a pure JavaScript solution on [GitHub](https://github.com/GabrielDelepine/smooth-scroll) that you might be able to adapt for what you need.

As for your original function `window.scrollTo({ top: 300, left: 0, behavior: "smooth" });` I think that’s always going to bring you to a position 300 pixels from the top of the window, and may not work for IE or Safari (I don't think they support the options version of scrollTo).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't know what is going on with my HTML, but this setup doesn't work either. I don't use jQuery so I tried the one from GitHub but it didn't change anything. Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: Can you edit your question to include all of your code so the problem can be reproduced? It may be that there’s something else in your code that’s causing the scroll not to work.

Comment: My whole HTML code is 200 lines with a CSS which is 500 lines. I will try a new blank file only with the mentioned code and let you know if it works.